# Create variable based on an observation further down in data set in R

Tags: r

I need to create a new variable that's based on information from an observation further down in the data set that meets a specific criteria. The criteria could be met in the next observation or could be several rows down.

I'm a beginner in R and haven't been able to make any progress on the solution.

I have a data frame (df) with the following variables:

```
event        event time  
pass            10.10  
failed block    10.20
failed check    10.21  
reception       10.25
pass            17.60
reception       17.65
```

I need to create a variable called reception time that returns the time of the reception for each pass, so it looks like:

```
event         event time   reception time  
pass            10.10          10.25  
failed block    10.20            NA
failed check    10.21            NA  
reception       10.25            NA  
pass            17.60          17.65  
reception       17.65            NA
```

There could be 50 or more lines in between pass and reception.

Comment: In your data, does every pass have a reception? (Or might there be an interception, or something else?)

Comment: If every pass has a reception, then something like `df$reception_time = NA; df$reception_time[df$event == "pass"] = df$event_time[df$event == "reception"]`. But if the data is more complicated, this will not work.

Comment: @Gregor I think that should work well, as long as the data starts with a `pass` and it is always `followed` by a `reception` at a later point.

Comment: @Mihai it doesn't matter if the data **starts** with a `pass` - what matters for my method to work is that (a) there are the same number of passes and receptions, and (b) that they are in the same order (1st pass is associated with 1st reception, 2nd pass with 2nd reception, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack!

This is a bit klunky but it works for your example.

> df1

```
         event event.time
1         pass      10.10
2 failed block      10.20
3 failed check      10.21
4    reception      10.25
5         pass      17.60
6    reception      17.65
```

Utilizing the packages `dplyr` for the pipes and `tidyr` for `fill`

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(reception.time = ifelse(event == "reception", event.time, NA)) %>% 
  fill(reception.time, .direction = "up") %>% 
  mutate(reception.time = ifelse(event == "pass", reception.time, NA)
```

**Output**

> df2

```
         event event.time reception.time
1         pass      10.10          10.25
2 failed block      10.20             NA
3 failed check      10.21             NA
4    reception      10.25             NA
5         pass      17.60          17.65
6    reception      17.65             NA
```

**Data**

> dput(df1)

```
df1 <- structure(list(event = c("pass", "failed block", "failed check", 
"reception", "pass", "reception"), event.time = c(10.1, 10.2, 
10.21, 10.25, 17.6, 17.65)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @campbeb2, Glad to hear that. Looks like you are also fortunate to have several answers using different methods. Don't forget to read the help center section on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). tl:dr - If you feel like the answers are valid (i.e. answered your question) please upvote them and make sure to also use the check next to the one that you feel best answers your question.  Also, make sure you visit the [Stack Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve what you need using the [`which`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html) function of `base` `R`, assuming two things:

1. that your dataframe always starts with a `pass` (i.e., a `pass` occurs before a `reception`)
2. every `reception` that follows at a later point in time applies to the previous `pass`

If that is the case (i.e., if not, provide more details), then this should do:

```r
# Define variables.
event <- as.factor(c("p", "fb", "fc", "r", "p", "r"))
time <- c(10.10, 10.20, 10.21, 10.25, 17.60, 17.65)

# Create data frame.
data <- data.frame(event, time)
data

#   event  time
# 1     p 10.10
# 2    fb 10.20
# 3    fc 10.21
# 4     r 10.25
# 5     p 17.60
# 6     r 17.65

# Create result column.
data$reception <- NA
data

#   event  time reception
# 1     p 10.10        NA
# 2    fb 10.20        NA
# 3    fc 10.21        NA
# 4     r 10.25        NA
# 5     p 17.60        NA
# 6     r 17.65        NA

# Compute.
data$reception[which(data$event == "p")] <- data$time[which(data$event == "r")]
data

#   event  time reception
# 1     p 10.10     10.25
# 2    fb 10.20        NA
# 3    fc 10.21        NA
# 4     r 10.25        NA
# 5     p 17.60     17.65
# 6     r 17.65        NA
```

Comment: the data frame won't always start with a pass (thinking about it, I don't think it ever will start with one). Throughout the data frame there might be 500 or so passes but they'll always be embedded somewhere in the middle

Comment: It doesn't have to start with a `pass`, as long as a `pass` must occurs before a `reception`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your data correctly, adding a grouping variable (e.g. `event_n`) could be helpful for further analyses.

If `reception` is always the last occurence before a new series of event, you could use the `last()` function from `dplyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~event,        ~event_time,  
  "pass",        10.10,
  "failed block",10.20,
  "failed check",10.21,
  "reception",   10.25,
  "pass",        17.60,
  "reception",   17.65)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(event) %>% 
  mutate(event_n = sequence(n())) %>% 
  ungroup()

df2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   event        event_time event_n
#>   <chr>             <dbl>   <int>
#> 1 pass               10.1       1
#> 2 failed block       10.2       1
#> 3 failed check       10.2       1
#> 4 reception          10.2       1
#> 5 pass               17.6       2
#> 6 reception          17.6       2

df2 %>% 
  group_by(event_n) %>% 
  mutate(reception = if_else(event == "pass", last(event_time), NA_real_))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   event_n [2]
#>   event        event_time event_n reception
#>   <chr>             <dbl>   <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 pass               10.1       1      10.2
#> 2 failed block       10.2       1      NA  
#> 3 failed check       10.2       1      NA  
#> 4 reception          10.2       1      NA  
#> 5 pass               17.6       2      17.6
#> 6 reception          17.6       2      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Does this answer work with your data?